# Horizontal scrollbar in ie-11 due to css transform translate property

Tags: css, scrollbar, transform, translate

When I am using this css to make an element center into a container then everything is ok except ie-11. In ie-11 a horizontal scroll apper bottom of the page. When i remove width:100% from this css then scroll remove but i need this width.   you can see the problem in this page http://www.azayabeachresortgoa.com/wellness/

```
.box_center {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        z-index: 100;
        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually remove a lot of that stuff and end up with similar positioning, see [image: this screenshot]

If you don't want to revisit that (I suggest you do), you can simply add:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

Or add an `overflow: hidden` to one of the `.box_center`'s closer relatives.

Comment: Hi Xhynk, body { overflow-x: hidden; } is working for me. but now my question is , is it a good practice to use overflow property to body tag?

Comment: Not particularly. That's why I mentioned that you should revisit how you've structured it. I was able to get a similar (not pixel perfect) layout to what you have by removing a lot of the other CSS and maybe adding a rule or two - and it didn't have the overflow issue. Hiding the x-overflow on the body can often be seen as "hacky", but generally if it works, it works.

Comment: Xhynk, only the width :100% is the problem in this rule giving problem but I need that width. If I will remove the width then scroll will remove. Otherwise I don't know which properties I have to remove.
So if anybody has logical answer then plz reply